# Pyro5 : how to connect between different machines

Tags: python, chat, pyro

I am a student who is trying to pass a requirement. I only knew python and pyro5 because of this requirement.

I have a code from https://github.com/irmen/Pyro5/tree/master/examples/chatbox which is the sample documentation for pyro5. I was able to make it run on a virtual machine (both server.py and client.py) and it is running perfectly.

Now I am trying to make it work between 3 different machines.
Server, Client1 and Client 2.

My understanding is that I need to make sure that the server where the client.py file is the same as the ip hosting the server.py.

**Server.py** code for daemon set-up is as follows :
[image]

**Note **: I am running pyro5-ns in one of my terminals for the server.

**Client.py** has
[image]

**The error : **But I am getting "Pyro5.errors.CommunicationError: cannot connect to ('localhost', 9090): [Errno 111] Connection refused"...
"Failed to locate the nameserver") from x Pyro5.errors.NamingError: Failed to locate the nameserver

Am I missing a step here? To reiterate this code runs if server.py and client.py both run on the same machine. My goal is to let 3 or machine to chat.

Is it possible to use Pyro5.Daemon.serveSimple which I got from this thread but its for Pyro4 ([Pyro4: Failed to locate the nameserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499331/pyro4-failed-to-locate-the-nameserver))? I am not  sure how to configure the code though.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out by trial and error.

1. Assigned the ip to the named instance of the server by
   using pyro5-ns -n ,
2. then changing  namedserver parameter to ns.register(, uri)
3. then changing the proxy parameters of the client code from PYRO:PYRONAME to PYRO:PYRO.namedinstance:port.